# Objective c: Need SDK to unzip .7z file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unzip, 7zip

I would like to unzip .7z files in objective-c (for mac dev). I am using SSZipArchive, which is really nice, but it will not help me unzip 7z. Could you guys recommend me a good sdk to unzip the 7z? I also need to keep track of progressing during unzipping.(Like the percentage done..) Thanks!!

Comment: I am using to unzip on mac instead of ios. Is it working for mac also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Check the Source Code developed by Mo Dejong at [7zip decompresson SDK](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex7). It's based on `LZMA SDK 9.21 beta`. It includes only decode functions and the adler checksum logic is disabled at compile time, to improve performance.

GoodLuck !!!

Comment: Have you used this before? Is it possible to check progress during unzipping? or I need to write delegate by myself? Thanks

Comment: @YUFENG : Truly Speaking : I have never used this before. :(

Comment: Ok, I downloaded that sdk. I will take a look at it. Thanks for your help !! :)